# Verb for having a seizure

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word, medical or otherwise, for having a seizure?

The best I can come up with is convulsing or flailing.  Any better ones?

Comment: "seizing" should do just fine.

Comment: If you actually want people to understand you, say *having a seizure*.

Comment: Medically, if a patient starts having an seizure right in front of us, we'll say, *he's seizing*, for the sake of brevity and quick coordinated response, but we usually refer to them as seizures (*have you had any seizures in the last 6 months?*). *Seize* is too often used in the manner of *carpe diem* to be a useful term. Spasm, fitting, bucking/writhing are non-specific. Convulsing is acceptable, though one can convulse with laughter/other. What are your objections to *having a seizure*? It's proper and precise. People *flail* without seizing. That's why restraints are used.

Comment: I've heard "fitting" (in the sense of "having a fit") used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about "spasm?" It's traditionally defined as a noun, though I've also seen it defined as an intransitive verb:

> When convulsing, your body spasms.

Answer (score 3):

To **[seize](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Seize)** can be used as an intransitive verb with the meaning:

- To exhibit symptoms of seizure activity, usually with convulsions.

**[To shake](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Shake)** meaning to tremble, mainly in the expression having **the shakes**

- Uncontrollable trembling, as in a person who is cold, frightened, feverish, or ill. Often used with the: was suffering from a bad case of the shakes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a linguist by any means but with one of my foster dogs that has seizures, I've taken to making the word into a verb. For example: my dog seizured last night, my dog is seizuring right now.  It may not be a real word but people know what I mean when I say it.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much [any noun can be verbed](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/305782/to-science-the-sht-out-of-something)

Comment: I found some examples for "seizured rats" on Google. Some were scholarly articles.

Answer (score 0):

Consider "**to buck and writhe**" and "[**get/take sick**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/get%20sick) **with convulsions**."

> *He falls on the floor and starts [**bucking and writhing**](http://www.fifa.com/aboutfifa/socialresponsibility/news/newsid=944076/). He's having an epileptic fit: a doctor jogs over and tends to him*.
>
> *When I was small, I [**got sick with convulsions**](http://www.abs-cbnnews.com/pinoy-migration/06/11/08/pinoy-artist-sells-five-paintings-one-hour-holland) and everyone thought I was dying*.

Comment: That might also describe a child throwing a tantrum. It's nice imagery, but not really specific to seizures.