# "To science the sh*t out of something"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, nouns, phrase-requests, word-usage

In [**The Martian**](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt3659388/) movie, Matt Damon (Watney), when left stranded on Mars with very limited resources to survive, says:

> **Mark Watney:** In the face of overwhelming odds, I'm left with only one option, I'm gonna have to ***science*** the shit out of this.

Apparently,

1. Celebrity scientist, Neil Degrasse Tyson [loved this quote](https://mobile.twitter.com/neiltyson/status/610997574808395777?lang=en). And so did I.
2. A [Quora post](http://qr.ae/RODKJs) says

   > Watney's a scientist. He's going to use scientific method to solve his problems. It's more obvious in the book - he does a lot of calculations.
   > eg. He drives the rover around in circles logging how much energy it uses to test his hypothesis for carrying hab solar panels on a trailer, keeping within walking distance of the hab. He doesn't just do something and hope it works first time, like MacGyver ('80s TV show).

So you probably get the idea what it means ***to science the shit out of something***.

That is, to practically experiment a lot (and a lot more), in this case, for survival; instead of simply hoping to survive by sheer luck.

<del>1. What would be a better way to convey the same meaning?</del> (too broad)

2. Is there a better word to use as a verb here?
3. Is it okay to use certain nouns (like science) in place of verbs? If so, what's the technique called?

Comment: Verbification of nouns is currently then fad on the Internet: *I can't brain today*, *I forgot how to dog*, etc. It's intentionally precious. But it's quite common outside that trend, and has been going on forever.

Comment: Well-researched question +1). Probably you will get an answer that says "almost all the English nouns could work as verbs". One question per post seems to be the policy and I think Question 1 and 2 could be merged into one.

Comment: Just my 2 cents... Movies often don't (and they don't have to) follow the syntaxes, grammar and semantics of a language. This is done to add some humorous undertones or dramatic effect to the dialogues and overall screenplay. If you replace the dialog("to science the shit out") with something else, I don't think it would have created the same amount of impact as it has now.

Comment: -1 for a very sloppy use of the word "better". If you're interested in precise answers, ask precise questions.

Comment: You will find this question very interesting, [Which nouns can be used as verbs?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78354/which-nouns-can-be-used-as-verbs).

Comment: It might be OK to verb any noun in _informal_ speech, but not in more formal or standard speech, only those nouns that have been verbified consistently over some time.

Comment: [Relevant xkcd.](https://xkcd.com/1443/)

Comment: @DanBron  Since it's ok to verb any noun,  "verbify" is rejected as being extraletterific.  :-)

Comment: heck, relevant [Calvin and Hobbes](http://www.gocomics.com/calvinandhobbes/1993/01/25/) (from 1993)!

Comment: I'm not sure there *is* a "better" way to express that.  It's succinct and gets the point across quite well.

Comment: So we can verb nouns and noun verbs, basically. :)

Comment: @NVZ - Well, you just verbed a noun, so it must be OK.

Comment: I read the book, and Mark didn't really do much science (hypothesizing, experimenting, etc.) but just lots of engineering (applying existing knowledge, including math, chemistry, etc. to solve problems). Since *engineer* is already a transitive verb, it would work just fine instead of "science" in this sentence. It just wouldn't have as much punch or flair. Yes, he did testing, but it was testing of his technology designs, not testing of the properties of matter or the laws of chemistry.

Comment: Relevant [t-shirt](https://www.topatoco.com/merchant.mvc?Screen=PROD&Product_Code=QC-SCIENCEVERB)

Comment: Try the "Search Q&A" box at the top-right corner on this page with "verbing" -- Have fun!

Comment: See [the recent article by Ben Zimmer](https://stronglang.wordpress.com/2015/09/16/im-going-to-have-to-science-the-shit-out-of-this/) and [this one too](https://stronglang.wordpress.com/2016/02/11/i-agreed-the-fuck-out-of-it/)

Comment: See: "Joss Whedon dialog" for many many examples.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/292546/is-to-anagram-an-established-verb

Comment: @Glen_b For ELUers, *sth* is a "word," having been internalized way back with the first grammar lessons. :)

Comment: @Kris I seem to be an ELUer (I read, ask, answer, etc here) so this cannot be universally true: my first grammar lessons did not include any such word, nor was such a "word" ever used in my presence by anyone I ever met until I was in my late 40s (&if it's a word rather than abbreviation, how is it pronounced?). Unless you're saying that only people whose background includes this\* can be regarded as ELUers (\*counting it as a word from the time of their first grammar lessons), my point stands -- expanding "sth" to the thing it abbreviates makes it accessible to people you count as non-ELUers

Comment: @NVZ; Stack Exchange has a strong no-bad-language-in-titles policy, because Hot Network Questions (which this has reached) can get all SE sites banned by company filters.  Feel free to use whatever language you like in the body of posts, including complaints about the policy (which should probably be on Meta Stcak Exchange).

Comment: @LarsH it's similar to the fact that rocket science is easy (put some fuel in a tube and set fire to it), but rocket engineering is extremely difficult (do so with useful results and without blowing yourself up).

Comment: Just heard another variation of this phrase. On the March 15 episode of NCIS, Tony says "Let's Abby the hell out of this thing." Abby is the team's tech geek, and he and the rest of the team was entering her lab after being informed that she'd made a breakthrough in the case.

Comment: You can verb any noun.

Comment: Au contraire, arrivalin, this question has received a lot of attention—and that was before your 200-point bonus came along.

Comment: @arivalin, Sven took the words out of my mouth, 7K views is a very healthy number of views, and there's even an answer with 60 upvotes. You have to say what type of answer  "you" are looking for. NVZ does not award the bounty.

Comment: @Mari-LouA If I asked another question, that would be immediately closed as duplicate. The existing answers are interesting, but... *differing*. I guess I should have chosen a different reason for bounty. 200 is too much, but I'm new here, so, mistakes happen.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm noticing a lot of down votes now, what have I done? Any idea?

Comment: Matt Damon, when Marsed, and resourced very little, speeched, "I am optioned with one thing: expletiving the science out of this."

Comment: I have a word, but is Portuguese. Seeing the popularity of this question, I am scared to post it as an answer. Would you consider it?

Comment: @vickyace sure, I'd like it. I didn't put the bounty, though. :)

Comment: @NVZ http://www.cracked.com/article_17251_the-10-coolest-foreign-words-english-language-needs_p2.html read desenrascano  http://portuguesefordummies.blogspot.in/2007/03/question-5-what-is-desenrascano.html

Comment: @NVZ just something interesting.

Comment: Just make sure you [stand back](http://store-xkcd-com.myshopify.com/products/try-science).

Answer (score 68):

The rhetorical term for the phenomenon you describe is catachresis.

Catachresis has been [defined](http://www.virtualsalt.com/rhetoric5.htm#Catachresis) by Robert A. Harris as "an extravagant, implied metaphor using words in an alien or unusual way." A noun, for example, could be used as a verb, as in the case of "I'm gonna have to science . . .."
Harris gives an example which is similar to Matt Damon's sentence:

> The little old lady turtled along at ten miles per hour.

A good catachresis creates a word picture. The sentence which contained the word *turtled* as a verb may solidify, so to speak, the writer's or speaker's idea in the mind of the reader or listener.

The image of an old lady *turtling along* cements itself in someone's mind more readily than a mere verbal description such as, "The old lady plodded along slowly" (although the word *plodded* is better than an average word, such as *walked*).

In conclusion, while the expression "to science something" may not serve to create a word picture, that one word may get a listener to think of the elements of the scientific method (e.g., the control of variables, careful measurements, and hypothesis-making and hypothesis-testing). Now that's an efficient use of words!

Comment: I like this, but it doesn't tackle the second half of the sentence, where tacking "the shit out of this" as opposed to this implies a task of greater magnitude, intensity, or risk.

Comment: @corsiKa: Good point! Robert Harris's example could be expanded for added magnitude and intensity by inserting the word "defiantly" after "turtled." So you have, "The little old lady turtled along defiantly at ten miles per hour." That provides a funny picture, at least in my mind, of an old lady who doesn't give a s_ _ t if she's frustrating the heck out of the people behind her! Don

Comment: -1 Sorry, but that's just **not** it. "I will speak daggers to her." has no verbing. Furthermore, catachresis is far more inclusive, very broad. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catachresis     http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/catachresis

Comment: "turtled" is also a pun on "hurtled" which would be the word you'd expect to see in such a phrase.

Comment: A pedantic remark about the turtling: she's fairly clearly *driving* rather than *walking*, so both "plodded" and "walked" would be unsatisfactory for reasons of correctness rather than vividity. (Walking at 10mph would be *really fast*.)

Comment: @Kris: True enough. Then again, I didn't say daggers was a verb, nor did Harris for that matter. I suppose had he wanted to illustrate catechresis with a noun/verb, he would have. By the way, the Wikipedia entry for catechresis also includes this information: "[Catechresis is] also the name given to many different types of figure of speech in which a word or phrase is being applied in a way that significantly departs from conventional (or traditional) usage." Maybe that means "science," as in "science the s_ _ t out of it" does contain an instance of catechresis. Just a thought. Don

Comment: The "turtled" sentence is funny, but I don't really see much similarity with the sentence from *The Martian*.

Answer (score 30):

This  question can be approached as one of **register**.

First, there's an expletive used as an intensifier:

beat the crap out of...knock the hell out of...kick the shit out of...punch the bejeezus out of... etc

> He knocked *the hell out of* Joe Schmoe in the heavyweight bout last
>   year.

Second, there's the use of the noun **science** as a verb, occupying a particular position in a common intensifier pattern, and thereby associating *doing scientific stuff* with punching, beating, kicking, knocking, etc.  Using the noun as a verb is like using a wrench as a hammer. These two things, noun as (crude) verb, and noun-verb occupying the position of kick, beat, punch in the intensifier pattern, turn his scientific activity into a *macho* or *survivalist* enterprise. He is momentarily feigning the register of the macho survivalist.

There's self-deprecating humor (lab geeks laughing at themselves) but also a real swaggering pride taken in his possessing the knowledge that may save his life, the kind of knowledge that could save his home planet's life some day.

So, when the OP asks for a "better" way to say this, the question arises, what does "better" mean?  A more polite, or a less swaggering way?  That wouldn't be better from the point of view of the story and character. A neutral way would be to say that he intends to use every scientific method at his disposal.

Answer (score 15):

Using a noun as a verb is called "verbing" which, appropriately enough, is itself an example of the phenomenon it describes.  It's often looked down on as slangy and inelegant, but many common verbs actually started as nouns.

> In a single work day, we might *head* a task force, *eye* an opportunity, *nose* around for good ideas, *mouth* a greeting, *elbow* an opponent, *strong-arm* a colleague, *shoulder* the blame, *stomach* a loss, and finally, perhaps, *hand* in our resignation.
>
> ...
>
> Psychologist Steven Pinker estimates that up to a fifth of English verbs are derived from nouns--including such ancient verbs as *rain*, *snow*, and *thunder* along with more recent converts like *oil, pressure, referee, bottle, debut, audition, highlight, diagnose, critique, email*, and *mastermind*.
>
> http://grammar.about.com/od/grammarfaq/f/verbingfaq.htm

Answer (score 14):

> Is it okay to use certain nouns (like science) in place of verbs? If so, what's the technique called?

I notice that no one has given the *classical* answer to your second question there. The technique is traditionally called "anthimeria" or "antimeria", meaning "against the part". That is, using one part of speech in a manner contrary to its usual function in a sentence.  See Wikipedia for numerous examples. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthimeria

Answer (score 8):

As others have mentioned, this is colloquially known as "verbing" a noun. The formal term for this in linguistics is [conversion, or zero-derivation](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Conversion_(word_formation)):

> In linguistics, conversion, also called zero derivation, is a kind of word formation; specifically, it is the creation of a word (of a new word class) from an existing word (of a different word class) without any change in form.

Answer (score 5):

Answering question 1) and 2) only.

Some obvious more proper ways to say it would be to use "[scientific method"](http://socratic.org/questions/how-can-the-scientific-method-be-used-to-solve-a-problem) or a variation of it somewhere in the sentence. It's the most common term.

> I'm going to solve this problem using science
>
> I'm going to scientifically solve this problem
>
> I'm going to use the scientific method to solve this problem
>
> I'm going to use the scientific method of problem solving

Oh , and if you really , really want to  use a verb:

> I'm going to scientize this problem
>
> "to treat scientifically, to apply science to something" ([Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/scientize))

I find it awkward, but it's a verb apparently in use since the [1800](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=scientize&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cscientize%3B%2Cc0)'s.

Comment: Judging from the remarks in the question, "research" or "experiment" was meant.

Answer (score 3):

This is called [verbing](http://grammar.about.com/od/grammarfaq/f/verbingfaq.htm); see extended description at the link or in other answers.
Here's the obligatory/famous Calvin & Hobbes on the subject:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try [macgyver](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/macgyver). It means to make, assemble or repair something by ingenious and inventive improvisation. In other simple terms it means to use ingenuity to fix or remedy a problem using only the tools available at hand.

Mark watney macgyvered a makeshift roof to make room for his equipment ans supplies.

Comment: In your question itself, this word is mentioned, @NVZ didn't you see?

Comment: @arrivalin good one. And I only read the questions. What are the odds.