# Is the word "bonsai" used both as a noun and a verb?

Tags: meaning

Is it common to use the word "bonsai" as a verb as in the following passage? And what does it mean?

> If you've ever crammed into the back of a Toyota with one or more males over the age of seven, you're likely familiar with the phenomenon recently popularized as manspreading.
>
> A target of women's websites and public transit authorities, the practice involves the widening of a man's legs while seated such that those adjacent must **bonsai** themselves into what little sittable space remains in a bus or airplane row.

Source: "The manspreading epidemic: Is it really an epidemic?", [CNN](http://edition.cnn.com/2016/06/22/travel/manspreading-public-transport/)

[image: CNN]

Comment: It's a simple case of one-off "verbing" a noun.  Unless it becomes a common usage it does not represent a new role for the noun.

Comment: Verbing weirds language.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it can be used as a verb and CNN used it that way.

[Verbification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_(word_formation)) in English is common and the linked Wikipedia article explains there are thousands of them:

> Examples of verbification in the English language number in the
>   thousands, including some of the most common words such as mail and
>   e-mail, strike, talk, salt, pepper, switch, bed, sleep, ship, train,
>   stop, drink, cup, lure, mutter, dress, dizzy, divorce, fool, merge, to
>   be found on virtually every page in the dictionary. Thus,
>   verbification is by no means confined to slang and has furnished
>   English with countless new expressions: "access", as in "access the
>   file", which was previously only a noun, as in "gain access to the
>   file". Similar mainstream examples include "host", as in "host a
>   party", and "chair", as in "chair the meeting". Other formations, such
>   as "gift", are less widespread but nevertheless mainstream.

When a noun like 'bonsai' is used in the linked article, there is no doubt that it is used as a verb as it follows the modal verb *must* and you should use a verb before the reflexive pronoun *themselves* to make sense.

The noun '[bonsai](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bonsai)' comes from the Japanese noun ' 盆栽 ぼんさい' and it means

> a tree or shrub that has been **dwarfed**, as by pruning the roots and
>   pinching, and is grown in a pot or other container and trained to
>   produce a desired shape or effect.

[Dictionary.com]

> ...Those adjacent must bonsai themselves into what little sittable
>   space...

could be rephrased to

> ...those adjacent must **cram** themselves into what little sittable space...

Related question: [“To science the sh*t out of something”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/305782/to-science-the-sht-out-of-something)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, good enough to get one down-vote, whoever the downvoter is.

Comment: I am more curious about what happened to all the comments.

Comment: Where did you get the kanji and hiragana from? They appear to be incorrect, the correct Chinese (and Japanese) word for `bonsai` is [盆栽](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%9B%86%E6%A0%BD) , literally "pot cultivation".

Comment: @MarchHo Thanks. I got the wrong one and corrected it.

Answer (score 4):

Officially it is a noun. The word comes from the combination of two Japanese words:

> *“Bon”* is a dish or thin bowl (“a modified vessel which has been divided or cut down from a deeper form”).
>
> *“Sai”* is a tree or other growing plant which is planted – “planted,” as would be a halberd or spear or pike stuck into the ground.
>
> *“Bonsai”* thus means or denotes “a tree which is planted in a shallow container".
>
> -- [Bonsai Empire](http://www.bonsaiempire.com/origin/what-is-bonsai)

However the noun has unofficially been adopted for use as a verb (in much the same way that the verbs *to hoover<sup>[[1]](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hoover)</sup>* and *to google* have been adopted from the nouns and phrases *to vacuum using a Hoover* and *to search using the Google search engine*) to mean *to make small like a bonsai*.

The English language is littered with such noun-orientated phrases that have been shortened into a single verb using the noun as the new verb. Is it correct? It's evolution.

So in your quoted phrase, to *bonsai oneself* would be *to make oneself small like a bonsai* to fit into a small space (like a *Bon*) caused by the "manspreading".

Comment: Side note: I believe "hoover" as a verb is an Australianism. Americans say "vacuum".

Comment: @Jay It's very much a British thing too. It's also something I never do if I can help it ;)