# Gentle alternative for "abused the crap out of something"

Tags: formality, speech

I really like the saying "abused the crap out of....." because it feels strong. Recently I am asked to prepare a speech and I don't think it's appropriate to use the saying. Are there any formal ways of saying it?

Thanks.

Edit: to add a bit of context this is my graduation speech. I'm trying to say something like "abused the crap out of the freedom I got", but I'm pretty sure I'll use this again in the future.

Comment: See also: [“To science the sh*t out of something”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/305782/50044)

Comment: "I took advantage of the freedom given to me" or "I exploited the freedom given to me to its fullest"

Comment: Yeah, don't say "took advantage" or "exploit".  It's verbose and ambiguous.

Comment: *Abused* is already a strong word when used in a formal setting; is the hyperbolizing modifier really necessary? Compare at *murdered* versus *violently murdered*.

Comment: You *pushed the limits* of your freedom.

Answer (score 0):

How much formality do you need?  If you just want something less vulgar, you could say, "they drove it like it was stolen and parked it like it was rented."

For true formality, just say, "severely abused".

Comment: In front of my teachers and a lot of parents formal. Surprisingly I haven't heard that saying before! It sure sounds very good. Thanks!

Comment: @SeeJianShin -- If you don't want to drive, you can ride [shotgun](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQqtbJmVFFs).

Comment: @Mari-LouA he actually gave the answer before I edited the post.